# What is a pager?

Tags: pager

I saw "pager" in several places:

> `less` is a terminal pager program on Unix
>
> option `-P` for `man` Specify which output pager to  use.

What is a pager? How is it related to and different from a terminal? Thanks.

Comment: `less` is the gnu `more`. (gnu can be pronounced the same as new)

Comment: According to the man page, less is the opposite of more.

Comment: Just in case there's any confusion, "pager" may also refer to a GUI application which shows a miniaturized version of the desktop.

Comment: A pager is something like [this](http://goo.gl/2X2KR4).

Comment: As another example of a pager, you could also try: `| vim -R -` at the end of a command.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: No, [GNU is pronounced](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/pronunciation.en.html) with a hard "g" sound at the beginning, like "grew" but with an "n" instead of an "r".

Comment: Actually I wonder: If you have read "pager" in several manual pages, you have used a *pager* while reading those already, most likely. Basically a pager prevents you from seeing all pages at once ;-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As the name implies, roughly a pager is a piece of software that helps the user get the output one page at a time, by getting the size of rows of the terminal and displaying that many lines.

The most popular pagers in a UNIX text environment are `more` and `less`.
The latter is kind of a joke as `less` can actually do more then `more`.

Comment: what is like with and without a pager? Thanks.

Comment: if you don't pipe your output through a pager (`less`, `more` and `most` come to mind), that output will appear on your screen all at once and thus you might lose something if said output is bigger than the number of lines of your terminal.

Comment: You only need to use a pager if the output is longer than the terminal hight. However if the terminal has a scroll back, you may feel that you do not need it, as you can scroll back, but the pager still has the advantage of starting at the top. Scrolling back starts at the bottom.

Comment: @Tim, give it a try. Find a command that outputs lots of lines (more than a screen full), such as `ls` in a directory full of files. Then add `| less` to end of command. You should see just the first page. Then press space to go to next page.

Comment: Scroll back is also finite. A pager is not limited to any particular size.

Comment: Most pagers also provide extra features such as pattern searching and position marking.

Comment: (1) Another pager that’s available on some versions of Unix is [`pg`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pg_(Unix)). (2) While most (if not all) terminals have a finite scroll-back capacity, some pagers (e.g., `more`) cannot scroll back at all when the input is from a pipe. (3) An interesting wrinkle is that some pagers (in some environments) write into the terminal’s scroll-back memory, so you can quit the pager and then still scroll back and review (re-see?) its output. Others create a separate viewing environment, so, when you terminate the pager, its output vanishes. …

Comment: … (4) Another feature of (many) pagers is that they let you skip over some of the output (either by searching for a string or pattern, or by specifying a number of lines or screen/page-fuls to skip). This is especially useful when the pager’s output is stored in the terminal’s scroll-back memory (i.e., it determines how far back you need to scroll to look at the output from the command(s) _before_ you ran the pager).

Comment: ```pager``` is must for consoles where scroll buffering is not possible. ie: in grub rescue mode. you can't scroll.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to confirm the comments of @schaiba and @Faheem Mitha.

@schaiba :

> if you don't pipe your output through a pager (`less`, `more` and `most`
> come to mind), that output will appear on your screen all at once and
> thus you might lose something if said output is bigger than the number
> of lines of your terminal.

@Faheem Mitha:

> Scroll back is also finite. A pager is not limited to any particular
> size.

---

You can try easily by changing the terminal environment variables setttings

First, try `man bash` (You need a command manpage that's long enough. Google told me `man bash` is longest one) with default pager. (I don't know which it's the default one but whatever it definitely has one).

Then set `PAGER` to empty. (Need to `export` or it won't be written into terminal environment variables)

```
PAGER=
export PAGER
```

Again, try `man bash`. You will find that even if you sroll up, you can't see the beginning of the `man bash` page.

So now you(I) understand how pagers matter.

Comment: Actually I would recommend `man man`, specifically option `-P` in there.